# I need to better understand a fundamental nature of Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, object

If I declare an object as follows:

```
var foo.bar = new Object;
```

Does that automatically make foo an object?  If not and I want both foo and foo.bar to be objects do I need to use the following code:

```
var foo = new Object;
var foo.bar = new Object;
```

And if I create these two objects as above, is there a parent/child relationship between them or are they completely separate entities?

I apologize for the simple nature of my question, but I am trying to more fully understand the various ways data can be structured.

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers, especially with respect to the proper literal notation to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I declare an object as follows:
>
> ```
>   var foo.bar = new Object;
> ```
>
> Does that automatically make foo an object?

No. It's a syntax error;

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token `.`

> If not and I want both foo and foo.bar to be objects do I need to use the following code:
>
> ```
> var foo = new Object;
> var foo.bar = new Object;
> ```

No, that's again a syntax error. You should be using.

```
var foo = new Object;
foo.bar = new Object;
```

But it's more common to use [object literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers) these days;

```
var foo = {
    bar: {

    }
}
```

> And if I create these two objects as above, is there a parent/child relationship between them or are they completely separate entities?

They are completely separate entities. The only link between them is that `foo` holds a reference to `bar`. Something else can easily hold a reference to bar;

```
var baz = foo.bar;
// Now baz and foo.bar are both pointing to the same object

alert(baz === foo.bar); // true;
baz.attr = 1;
alert(baz.attr); // 1
alert(foo.bar.attr); // 1

delete foo.bar; // delete foo's reference to bar
alert(baz.attr); // still shows 1
alert(foo.bar.attr); // error, because we deleted `bar`.
```

[Try it yourself... http://jsfiddle.net/AMXLE/1](http://jsfiddle.net/AMXLE/1)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> var foo.bar = new Object;
> ```

That would throw a SyntaxError; the `.` character is not allowed in JavaScript variable names. This would work, though:

```
var foobar = new Object;
```

> var foo = new Object;
>      var foo.bar = new Object;

That won’t work for the same reason as before. Use this instead:

```
// using the `Object` constructor
var foo = new Object;
foo.bar = new Object;

// or just use an object literal:
var foo = {
  'bar': {}
};
```

> And if I create these two objects as above, is there a parent/child relationship between them or are they completely separate entities?

Both `bar` and `foo` are objects, but `bar` is a property of `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

That first example will cause an error, because `foo` has not previously been defined, but what you can do, is use object literals:

```
var foo = { bar: new Object() };
```

Or even:

```
var foo = { bar: {} };
```

In terms of your last question, `bar` becomes a property of `foo`.

Comment: in fact, literals are more preferable

Comment: It won’t error because `foo` has not been defined (in fact, it has been defined in OP’s example); it will throw a `SyntaxError` because of the `.` character which is invalid in a JavaScript variable name.

Comment: should simply be `var foo = {bar:{}};` because `{}` is the same as `new Object()`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I like to see it, is that objects in Javascript are exactly the same as associative arrays (aka hashtables, aka dictionaries), where each key is a string, and each value can be of any type, including `function`. So your code is **EXACTLY** the same as:

```
var foo = {};
foo["bar"] = {};
```

Or even:

```
var foo = {"bar": {}};
```